# View number of edits made in an Enterprise GDB?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, editing, versioning

I would like to see the total number of edits made in my Default.SDE before the reconcile/post/compress process. I know you can view the number of edits made in versions with the Version Changes tool but it wont allow it for the Default.

The data does not have to be specific, just total number of created features/deleted/modified features (one number for all edits works).

For example, if I run my reconcile/post/compress script every Friday, I want to be able to see how many edits were made to this gdb before I start the process.

I'm sure there has to be an easy solution for this or something arcpy can handle (preferred method would be arcpy so I can add this to my reconcile/post/compress script to print the number of edits so I can catalog in my invoices. But I am not finding much on GeoNet.

Comment: One thing you can do is capture the row counts in the Adds and Deletes tables. You'd have to do more sophisticated queries to determine how many insert, update, and delete transactions were present.

Comment: Was hoping this could be done in Catalog/arcpy but SQL Server queries may be my only option.

Comment: Any SQL query solution can be implemented in ArcPy through an arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute cursor, so now I need to figure out the syntax for this anyone familiar with it?

Comment: The cross-posted GeoNet question has SQL.  Instead of reposting my comments from there here, you should alter the question here to contain the SQL you intend to execute and the Python you have started to implement it, along with a description of where you have gotten stuck (unless the code works first time, which is quite possible, at which point you can answer this yourself).